# Hamcrest - print to console

Tags: java, junit, console, hamcrest, println

I'm testing a function called `generateRandomByteInRange`.
It fails and I want to see the exact value it gets (and not only that it was less than -127).
I tried to surround the assert with try - catch and when it fails to print to the console but nothing happened.

Function -

```
byte generateRandomByteInRange(int minVal,int maxVal) {
    Random rnd;
    rnd = new Random();
    return (byte) (rnd.nextInt(maxVal - minVal + 1) + minVal);
}
```

Test -

```
@Test
public void generateRandomByteInRange() {
    int res;
    int minVal,maxVal;

    minVal = 1;
    maxVal = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        res = AF.generateRandomByteInRange(minVal, maxVal);
        assertThat(res, is(both(greaterThanOrEqualTo(minVal)).and(lessThanOrEqualTo(maxVal))));
    }

    minVal = -127;
    maxVal = 128;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        res = AF.generateRandomByteInRange(minVal, maxVal);
        try {
            assertThat(res, is(both(greaterThanOrEqualTo(minVal)).and(lessThanOrEqualTo(maxVal))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(res);
        }

    }
}
```

The test fails and I get the following message (in the right)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hamcrest doesn't always do the greatest job in reporting back your value. If you take a closer look at the assertion message you got (bolding added for emphasis), you'd see that `-128` is in fact the offending value. You can confirm this by changing `res = AF.generateRandomByteInRange(minVal, maxVal)` to some faulty hard-coded value (e.g., `res = 400`) and observe the assertion message.

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: is (a value equal to or greater than <-127> and a value less than or equal to <128>)
>        but: a value equal to or greater than <-127> **<-128>** was less than <-127>

Regarding your attempt to catch the exception - while somewhat redundant (see above), you had a good idea, but you caught the wrong exception. When an assertion fails, an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) is thrown. This is an unchecked exception, and as such it extends `java.lang.Error` and not `java.lang.Exception` which you tried to catch. Just replace it with an explicit catch of `AssertionError` (or one of its base classes) and you should be OK.

Comment: You could add to not forget about **rethrowing** that exception. You still want the test to fail, don't you. No point in overlooking that a *passing* test actually printed an error to the console, to then forget about that error.